# How to get serial number of my monitor?

Tags: xorg

How can we get the serial number of monitor in ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

With a Linux system (Ubuntu), you can use ddcprobe.

run in a termial

```
sudo apt-get install xresprobe
```

then

```
sudo ddcprobe
```

You'll see lots of info about your graphics card. Then at the end, you'll see

```
monitorserial: xxxxxxx
monitorname: xxxxxx
monitorrange: xxxxxx
```

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: So, is it just blank? Are you getting an error message? Do tell.

Comment: yes  a blank message

Comment: Well, in that case your video card or monitor may not support reading this data from the monitor. Are you trying to set up X11? Or is there another purpose for this exercise? Because there may be another way to achieve the same result.

Comment: As Joachim said, you could also try read-edid. That's also available from Ubuntu's package repositories: sudo apt-get install read-edid

Comment: I use 2 monitors, but `ddcprobe` shows only 1 serial - how could I obtain the second?

Answer (score 3):

There's a software package called [read-edid](http://polypux.org/projects/read-edid/) that should help you get to pretty much all information the monitor gives away. The separate tools are called `get-edid` and `parse-edid`:

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
```

Comment: This does not provide the serial number.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the Monitor Make and Model?   You can not get the Monitor's serial number, 
but you can get the make & model once X is running:

you can look for it in /var/log/Xorg.0.log , e.g. grep '--' /var/log/Xorg.0.log
or in

Comment: For what it is worth, I can see both my monitor's serial number and model in the Xorg log file (search for "Serial No:").  If it isn't showing for you, then perhaps your monitor isn't providing it in the EDID info.

Answer (score 2):

install `edid-decode` first

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install edid-decode
```

then run this line

```
for file in `ls -1 /sys/class/drm/*/edid`; do text=$(tr -d '\0' <"$file"); if [ -n "$text" ]; then edid-decode "$file" | grep -e Manufacturer: -e Product; fi; done
```

on my machine, it gives below output

```
  Vendor & Product Identification:
    Manufacturer: DEL
    Display Product Serial Number: 'HT54DH3'
    Display Product Name: 'DELL U2723QE'
  Vendor & Product Identification:
    Manufacturer: DEL
    Display Product Serial Number: '9BHZCH3'
    Display Product Name: 'DELL U2720QM'
```

the `Display Product Serial Number` is the serial number you asked for